# Storing HTML in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, html-encode

I'm storing HTML and text data in my database table in its raw form - however I am having a slight problem in getting it to output correctly. Here is some sample data stored in the table AS IS:

```
<p>Professional Freelance PHP & MySQL developer based in Manchester.
<br />Providing an unbeatable service at a competitive price.</p>
```

To output this data I do:

```
echo $row['details'];
```

And this outputs the data correctly, however when I do a W3C validator check it says:

```
character "&" is the first character of a delimiter but occurred as data
```

So I tried using `htmlemtities` and `htmlspecialchars` but this just causes the HMTL tags to output on the page.

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: i don't know whether it is a good advice but if i were you i would have ignored it

Comment: Make sure that the validator is using the correct rules/doctype - XML/XHTML is not HTML and an unescaped & is *valid* in that context for HTML. However, `&amp;` will "always be safe" and should be preferred.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `&amp;` instead of `&`.

Comment: Simplest way to solve this problem. The data is `HTML` anyway.

Comment: I think you're correct.. since I'm storing HTML data then it should be safe enough to store the HTML entities.

Answer (score 5):

What you want to do is use the php function `htmlentities()`...
It will convert your input into html entities, and then when it is outputted it will be interpreted as HTML and outputted as the result of that HTML...
For example:

```
$mything = "<b>BOLD & BOLD</b>";
//normally would throw an error if not converted...
//lets convert!!
$mynewthing = htmlentities($mything);
```

Now, just insert `$mynewthing` to your database!!

Answer (score 2):

`htmlentities` is basically as superset of `htmlspecialchars`, and `htmlspecialchars` replaces also `<` and `>`.

Actually, what you are trying to do is to fix invalid HTML code, and I think this needs an ad-hoc solution:

```
$row['details'] = preg_replace("/&(?![#0-9a-z]+;)/i", "&amp;", $row['details']);
```

This is not a perfect solution, since it will fail for strings like: `someone&son;` (with a trailing `;`), but at least it won't break existing HTML entities.

However, if you have decision power over how the data is stored, please enforce that the HTML code stored in the database is correct.

Comment: This could break valid html. Consider a case where you have valid html like `... &amp; ...`, it would replace it with `... &amp;amp; ...`

Comment: Yes, but I think it can be made even better by using regex.

Comment: Now, with the space, you have a problem when the string is something like `Someone&son's`

Comment: I updated my answer with a regexp expression. There are still cases in which it will fail, but making it "perfect" requires actually recognizing and skipping individual HTML entities. Feel free to improve or to provide alternative (non regexp) solutions.

Comment: Since he has control over the content. The actual best solution would be to write the & as `&amp;` beforehand. This is actually a good practice with HTML in general, so there's no reason the HTML shouldn't be stored as valid in the database to begin with. (Even though the HTML content itself probably shouldn't be stored in the database to begin with, but that's a different story).

Answer (score 0):

In my Projects I use XSLT Parser, so i had to change `&nbsp;` to `&#160;` (e.g.). But this is the safety way i found...

here is my code

```
$html = trim(addslashes(htmlspecialchars(
        html_entity_decode($_POST['html'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'),
        ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'
    )));
```

And when you read from DB, don't forget to use stripslashes();

```
$html = stripslashes($mysq_row['html']);
```